# Proving absolute or conditionally convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

I have the following partial series - 
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty {a_n} 
$$
when 
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{n} &; \quad n \ \text{is even}\\   
 \frac{-1}{n^2} &; \quad n \ \text{is odd}\ .
\end{cases}$$
I would like to get some hints for proving

or disproving absolute or conditional convergence , Thanks!

Comment: This question was already posted elsewhere

Comment: The series diverge for both cases. The reason is that the positive part diverges since it's basically harmonic while the negative part converges.

Comment: @BigbearZzz , you are right, my bad

Comment: If someone can write down a detailed explanation it will be helpful , Thanks.

Comment: you have to prove that $\sum_n \frac{1}{2n}$  diverges while $\sum_n \frac{-1}{(2n+1)^2}$ converges. together it answers the question

Comment: @user1952009 I dont know any theorem for what this can be useful, can you enlighten me please? What theorems show that?

Comment: I don't find the equivalent of "séries de Riemann" in english, except maybe [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Applications)  so it is a basic fact, proven in any courses on series that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a}$ converges whenever $a > 1$, in particular when $a=2$

Comment: @user1952009 - can you please explain why you choose those two series? i got the overall idea but if you can explain it will be great.

Comment: what two series ?

Comment: $\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ and $\sum \frac{-1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Comment: @user1952009 I already know these facts... but I cant understand why from there you can prove the divergency of the question. I dont know any theorem that let you rearrange an alternating series in two sums like you are doing.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{2N} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2 n} - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$ ... the first term diverges when $N \to \infty$ while the second converges, hence $\sum_{n=1}^{2N} a_n $ diverges